# Adobe Acrobat Pro Submit a pdf to a user generated email?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

Using Adobe Acrobat Pro
I am filling out a form that will be used by a variety of people, each with their own team lead.  I want people to be able to fill out the form, type in the email of their team lead, and then have a submit button that will submit the form to that email.

Does anyone know what javascript I need to write to accomplish this?

I tried the Submit form function of the adobe acrobat button, but it doesn't allow me to customize the Mailto: form.

Edit:  I found Javascript that lets users fill in a text entry field that will then be the subject of the body once the users click the submit button.  Can someone who is more savvy than I rework this so that the email address is the one based on the user's entry?

Where "MyTextField" is the earlier user text field for the subject:

```
var customSubject = this.getField("MyTextField").value;
var mailtoUrl = "mailto:studiosupport@qoppa.com?subject=" + customSubject;
this.submitForm({
 cURL: mailtoUrl, bPDF:true
});
```

I'm trying to learn a bit about code as I look through this. Why would this workaround not work?

```
var customSubject = Tomato;
var mailtoUrl = "mailto:this.getField("MyTextField").value?subject=" + customSubject;
this.submitForm({
 cURL: mailtoUrl, bPDF:true
});
```

Comment: It would be too many leads to make templates for each ones, especially as they would change fairly frequently.  We don't have any corporate IT programmers that I am able to ask.

Comment: This looks great!  But I can't see what JavaScript was used.  I tried converting the XFA to pdf and it removed all of the associated actions on the file.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)  I retried the code with
var TextEntry1= this.getField("MyTextField").value;
var customEmail = "mailto:TextEntry1";
var mailtoUrl = customEmail+"?subject=";
this.submitForm({
 cURL: mailtoUrl, bPDF:true
});
and it worked, but then Outlook responded with Microsoft Outlook does not recognize "TextEntry1" so it looks like my email program won't connect with the code :(

Comment: I finally figured it out! Thank you so much for your help!!!  For some reason yours and my code didnt work, but this did:
var cToAddr = this.getField("CoopEmail").value;

// First, get the client CC email address
var cCCAddr = this.getField("ClientEmail").value;
// Set the subject and body text for the email message
var cSubLine = "Subject"
var cBody = "Thank you for submitting your form.\n" + "Bye"

this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody});

I have no idea what the difference was, but I would have given up if not for you!